# Mysql inner joins advanced, howto

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me with this query?
I have three tables (A;B;C)

```
A <--1....N---> B  <--1....N--->  C
```

I want all A rows having C.dates (the greatest)

Comment: greatest `c.date` for every `a` row or all `a` rows holding the greates `c.date` overall? Please post some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*, MAX(C.dates)
FROM A
JOIN B ON B.A_fk = A.id
JOIN C ON C.B_fk = B.id
GROUP BY A.id
```

This JOIN will exclude results which wont have LEFT join. That is, if any row from A wont have B row or any row from B wont have any C row, then the row wont show. To overcome this you can use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

```
SELECT A.*, MAX(C.dates)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_fk = A.id
LEFT JOIN C ON C.B_fk = B.id
GROUP BY A.id
```

**EDIT:** Sorry didnt noticed that you needed the greatest value of C.data. There you have it. You have to use MAX function in SELECT and GROUP BY A.id

Comment: Why if I want to add another table max() clause don-t work :( ?

Comment: @user1348023 you need to post your code somewhere. We cant tell just by that.

Comment: I have t1, t2, t3 joined all and group by for a count and two max clause ! One of the two max I could replace it by reading the ID field in order to DESC limit 1... but return me only one row ! Not row lists . thanks